# How do i create git branch and switch at a time when creating a branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am creating a branch with this command

```
git branch my-branch
```

and switch a newly created branch with another command

```
git checkout my-branch
```

Any idea about creating a branch and switch with one command

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) with `-b` to specify a new branch name

```
git checkout -b my-branch
```

From the docs

> Specifying `-b` causes a new branch to be created as if [git-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) were called and then checked out.

Comment: Note that in Git 2.23, if you switch to the new `git switch` command, the create-branch option is spelled `-c` there; otherwise all is exactly the same, even to the `-B` and `-C` variants.

Comment: What is the behavior if the branch already exists?

Answer (score 16):

`git switch -c newBranchName`

it will create a new branch starting at the current head
[official docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--cltnew-branchgt) and then switch to that branch